# Contact Form 7 post content to another side

Tags: post, get, contacts

I am using Conact form 7 on my wordpress side. I would like to post the inputs form the user with a post method on to another side.

Something like that www.example/?name=Tom

Is there away to do that?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I tried doing something like that. on_submit: "window.location.replace('http://example.com/?name='.[Name]);" .

Comment: With PHP $_post you can read the posted data, but the URL you are showing is showing an get variable.

Comment: You're right, I need the GET method. Could you give me an example of the Get method? Thank you so much for your help.